none of the available extractors could read stream in react native using expo-av
I  have an video component, in react native, from expo-av every time I try to play a video I get this error
playing db.w0: None of the available extractors (c, d, b, g, k, b, a0, d, h0, e, h, b, e, f, b, a) could read the stream.
here is the video component
     <Video
            source={{uri:video}}
            className="w-full h-48 items-center rounded-md bg-white/40 mt-3"
            resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
            useNativeControls
            shouldPlay
            onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status)=>{
               console.log("playing",status.error);
               if(status.error){
                  Alert.alert("Error","An error occurred when playing the video")
                  setPlay(false)
               }
               if(status.didJustFinish){
                  setPlay(false)
               }
            }}
          />

the video passed to source looks like this
https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1/storage/buckets/6628225b80d94b4a9caa/files/662d65a5c0cffdda932f/preview?width=2000&height=2000&gravity=top&quality=100&project=66280eb7c07473182569
it's in the right format mp4
how can get rid of the error, the platform is android
I am trying to play a video a user has uploaded to AppWrite

The video you provided is not working.
Make sure to use a valid URI.
And to test if your code works, change the URI to this one:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4

<Video 
source={{uri:"https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"}}
className="w-full h-48 items-center rounded-md bg-white/40 mt-3
resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
useNativeControls
shouldPlay
onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status)=>{
    console.log("playing",status.error);
    if(status.error){
        Alert.alert("Error","An error occurred when playing the video
        setPlay(false)
    }
    if(status.didJustFinish){
        setPlay(false)
    }
}}/>

